# Combobox CompositeCollection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I want two comboboxes with collection with empty element.

I Use two comboboxes with:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="itemEditPageComboBox"
  ...
  ItemsSource="{StaticResource ItemsColl}"
 ....
/>
Collections:
<CompositeCollection x:Key="ItemsColl">
  <ComboBoxItem Content="" />
 <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ElementsCollection}}" />
</CompositeCollection>

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ElementsCollection" Source="{Binding Path=...}" />
```

behaviour

Sequentially choose two comboboxes, after it - one of them is removed empty element.

Error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='ComboBoxItem'
```

Please tell me what to do?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same `ComboBoxItem` in two `ComboBoxes`, also the error should be quite clear: If you add a `ComboBoxItem` to a `ComboBox` which has an `ItemTemplate` defined, that won't be applied to that `ComboBoxItem` because it already has the type of the created containers. This error may or may not be a problem, depending on what you want.

If you want to use the collection for two `ComboBoxes` you should add a `string` or if you want something more complex an instance of a class (which should probably have an implicit `DataTemplate` associated with it). Do not add a `ComboBoxItem` directly.